# Why does this line break IE11 and Edge?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, scripting

this code goes with a javascript video player.
The question is about the line of code which I have commented out right now.  The line with onPlay...

If that line of code is not commented out it breaks in IE11 and MS  Edge.

There is no console error... our video player just never starts.   Any ideas on where to start?

```
events:
{
    //onPlay: function() { setTimeout(() => player.stop(), 5000); },
    onStop: function() { this.player.play(); },
    onEnded: function() { this.player.play(); },
    onError: function() { this.player.play(); }
}
```

If that line stays commented out... it works fine and the video plays.

Comment: arrow functions `=>` break IE - they don't get it - I'm surprised it breaks edge though - since [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) states Edge has always supported them

Comment: You have a syntax error in the line of `onError`. Acutally something you should check before asking a question.

Comment: @sboesch that would break ALL browsers - probably a typo when writing the code here only

Comment: `There is no console error` that too surprises me - IE11 will definitely complain

Comment: @sboesch if you mean the fact that there is no comma at the end of the "onError" line... I don't think a comma is needed since that is the last item...

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks.  is there a way to bind variables like that that won't break IE?

Comment: `() => player.stop()` === `function() { player.stop(); }` - or use a transpiler - ahh, but I didn't read the edited code ... hang on

Comment: I think `onPlay: function() { setTimeout(function() { this.player.stop()}.bind(this) , 5000); }` may do the trick